# How to fix the error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a problem with this and I know the code is too long and complex but here I go:
this is the data I am using:

```
Data:
date = dt.datetime(2018, 6, 26)

maturity_dtime = DatetimeIndex(['2020-04-07', '2020-08-07', '2020-12-07', '2023-12-07',
           '2027-12-07', '2032-12-07', '2040-02-07'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

curve = ['act/365','Lineal','Anual',
    [datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 27, 0, 0), 4.105922851627142e-05], 
    [datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 26, 0, 0), 0.001200502096981415], 
    [datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 26, 0, 0), 0.0034882824213942065], 
    [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 26, 0, 0), 0.006427227712844319], 
    [datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 26, 0, 0), 0.008915157135919838], 
    [datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 26, 0, 0), 0.011097508773927123], 
    [datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 26, 0, 0), 0.0171882727144943]]
```

Then I have this functions:

```
def day_count(start_date, end_date, basis):
    if basis == 'act/365':
        days = (end_date - start_date).days
    else:
        print('fail')
    return days

def year_fraction(start_date, end_date, basis):
    if basis == "act/365":
        yf = day_count(start_date, end_date,basis) / 360.0
    else:
        print('fail')
    return yf

def interpol_curva(date,maturity_date,curve):
    base=curve[0]
    interpol=curve[1]
    #compo_fg=curve[2]

    nrows=int(len(curve))

    if maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]: #Here is the mistake
        maturity_date=curve[nrows-1][0]
    if maturity_date<curve[3][0]:
        maturity_date=curve[3][0]

    r1=3

    while maturity_date>curve[r1][0] and r1<nrows-1:
        r1=r1+1

    r1=r1-1
    if r1==2:
        r1=3
    if r1>=nrows-1:
        r1=nrows-2

    r2=r1+1

    #t1=year_fraction_2(date, curve[r1][0], base)
    #t2=year_fraction_2(date, curve[r2][0], base)
    #tt=year_fraction_2(date, matDate, base)

    if base=='act/360' or base=='act/365':
        yf1=(maturity_date-curve[r1][0]).days
        yf2=(curve[r2][0]-maturity_date).days
        yftt=(curve[r2][0]-curve[r1][0]).days

    else:
        print("fail")

    if interpol=='Lineal':
        return (curve[r1][1]*yf2+curve[r2][1]*yf1)/yftt


def Discount_Factor_2(value_date,maturity_date,curve):
    basis=curve[0]
    Composition=curve[2]
    yf = year_fraction(value_date, maturity_date, basis)
    r=interpol_curva(value_date,maturity_date,curve)

    if Composition == "Anual":
        df = 1 / (1 + r * yf)
    else:
         print("fail")
    return df
```

Then I try to run the function Discount_Factor_2 and I get this error:

```
Discount_Factor_2(date,maturity_dtime,curve)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The mistake is in the line if `maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]`
I want to know if there is a way to fix it. Later I want to minimize the result of that function by changing the parameters that create the variable curve.
Thank you so much and sorry if it is not clear. Thank you for taking your time.

EDIT: Adding the complete traceback:

```
Discount_Factor_2(value_date, maturity_dtime, curve)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-9cbb6735a3e3>", line 1, in <module>
    Discount_Factor_2(value_date, maturity_dtime, curve)

  File "<ipython-input-20-181d050d0cd4>", line 251, in Discount_Factor_2
    r=interpol_curva(value_date,maturity_date,curve)

  File "<ipython-input-20-181d050d0cd4>", line 178, in interpol_curva
    if maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Can you also show your exception stack trace?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I edit it adding the traceback, I don't know if you mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your `if` statement -

```
if maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]
```

Think about what this does -

Let's say `maturity_dtime` is a `pd.Series` that looks like this -

```
2020-04-07
2020-08-07
2023-12-07
```

Now if you do `maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]`, this will check iteratively whether each element in `maturity_date` is greater than `curve[nrows-1][0]`

So, this will yield another `pandas.Series` which may look like this -

```
True
False
True
```

The `if` statement in python, being the simpleton, expects one `bool` value and you are just confusing it by providing a bunch of boolean values. So, either you need to use `.all()` or `.any()` (those are the usual to-do things) at the end depending upon what you want

Comment: Where I should write .any()

Comment: @Amartin on top of your `pd.Series` `if (maturity_date > curve[nrows-1][0]).any()`

Answer (score 1):

Check what you are selecting in `curve[nrows-1][0]` and in `maturity_date`. One of them must be an array with more than one element and thus cannot be compared with a single element.